# On Windows 7 x64, How can I disable multi-session in RDP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services

Currently, my desktop running Win7 supports multiple sessions under the same username, which can be annoying if I left an app open on one that I can't access from another. How can I disable this and only allow one session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have group policy applied to the machine, either locally or from the domain.  The relevant policy setting is named "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session" and can be found here:

- Computer Configuration

  - Administrative Templates

    - Windows Components

      - Remote Desktop Services

        - Remote Desktop Session Host

          - Connections